# Why Facebook Group Post successful in Facebook app and getting Error In API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Feature : Facebook Group Post Via Facebook Graph API
Steps for Reproduce Issue :

1. Add Facebook Group into your Account
2. Make sure you are join or admin of that group
3. Goto Facebook and Leave Group
4. Call Graph API with that particular Facebook Group (Multiple Images)
5. API Will be Failed with below response

> message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"A6EyMIvkT1yPwpo5ijyw"

6. Goto Facebook and check in that facebook group post is shown..

Expexted Result :

1. If Facebook Graph API return Failed then it will be not post into Facebook Group
2. If Facebook Group posted successfully then response must be success 200.